# How to retrieve multiple row from oracle 10g table through jsp page

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to retrieve multiple row from oracle 10g tables through JSP using prepare statement.

Answer (score 0):

The following JSP code creates a prepared statement:

```
String myquery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT = ?";
PreparedStatement mystatement = connection.prepareStatement(myquery);
```

The first line stores the SQL statement in a string variable called myquery , with a question mark ( ? ) serving as a placeholder for the SQL variable value. The second line creates a prepared statement object called mystatement .

Next, you assign a value to the SQL variable, as follows:

```
mystatement.setString(1, request.getParameter("myURLparam"));
```

The setString method assigns the value to the variable and takes two arguments. The first argument specifies the affected variable by its position (here, the first position in the SQL statement). The second argument specifies the variable's value. In this example, the value is provided by a URL parameter passed to the page.

Note: You must use different methods to assign non-string values to SQL variables. For example, to assign an integer to the variable, you would use the mystatement.setInt() method.

Finally, you generate the recordset, as follows:

```
ResultSet myresults = mystatement.execute();
```

Please find the sample code below from the below link http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-apps-l/how-to-connect-to-database-in-jsp-using-jdbc-drivers-to-oracle-database-1569382

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*"%> 
<%@ page import="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection" %> 
<% 
OracleConnection conn1 = null; 

ResultSet getCountRs = null; 

PreparedStatement getCountStmt = null; 
try{ 
conn1 = (OracleConnection)TransactionScope.getConnection(); 

getCountStmt = conn1.prepareStatement("SELECT 
PROMPT,FUNCTION_ID,SUB_MENU_ID FROM FND_MENU_ENTRIES_VL WHERE MENU_ID 
=:1 and prompt is not null"); 

getCountStmt.setInt(1,pMenuid); 

getCountRs = getCountStmt.executeQuery(); 
while(getCountRs.next()) 
{ 
prompt[x]=getCountRs.getString(1); 
function_id[x]=getCountRs.getInt(2); 

submenu_id[x]=getCountRs.getInt(3); 
x++; 
} 
} 
catch(exception e) {} 
%>
```